# Relection of light

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, reflection

If I recall my physics correctly, and it was a long time ago, when a photon strikes a reflecting surface that specific photon is not what is reflected--rather the photon excites an electron which ejects a new photon. My question is how does the new photon know it has to come out at the angle of incidence?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Imagining a light wave as a hail of photons is a poor description. The photons in a light wave are delocalised and have no well defined position. The classical description of a light wave is a far better description when considering reflection.

Comment: I had looked to see if this question had been addressed but didn't find it.  The link provided in 1 answered my question. Thanks.