# Reflection and absorption of light at atomic level?

Tags: optics, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, reflection

How does reflection and absorption of light work at atomic level? When does light pass straight through?Can anyone explain in detail please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain reflection laws at the atomic level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/). There are several other relevant questions on its Linked sidebar on the right.