# Reflection of Light from a surface

Tags: visible-light, photons, atomic-physics, reflection

What is reflection, is it the bouncing back of photon or re-emission of photon by first jumping to a higher energy state and then coming down due to interaction with incident photon?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I suggest that you look at the [derivation of the Fresnel reflection equations](http://physics.gmu.edu/~ellswort/p263/feqn.pdf), and see if that clears up your confusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain reflection laws at the atomic level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/)