# Rigorous derivation of "reflection of light from mirror" from QFT

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection

In the book "QED: The Strange Theory of Light and Matter" Feynman derives classical law of light reflection from mirror in a intuitive way from QED. but i want a more rigorous way from principles witch show details in context of QFT (or equivalently QED), for example why atoms of other matter and their arrangement don't behave so. and how mirror in quantum level is capable of such a interesting behavior.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2041/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/2451 and links therein.

Comment: QFT may *seem* magical, but it's not witchcraft. ; )