# How does reflection work at a quantum level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, reflection

Thinking of light in corpuscular form, how does the bouncing of a photon off a reflective surface work?
Is it the same photon bouncing off, or is it absorbed and re-emitted?

If it's bouncing, does it do so without deceleration/reacceleration?

If it's being absorbed and re-emitted, what physical process guarantees that it's re-emitted at the exact same angle as it inceded on the reflective surface?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/2451 and links therein.