# Why white body cannot emit photons (quantum level)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, reflection

As far as I've found [white body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) by definition reflects 100% of electromagnetic radiation (EMR). According to thermal equilibrium as I've read it (but not been able to fully agree with the proof - so feel free to answer that it is incorrect) if white body emits w/out absorption, temperature goes to zero and that contradicts thermal equilibrium. So if true, white body cannot emit EMR.

I could not find the answer to "Why white body cannot emit photons?" on the web, also could not get if/how links on reflectivity, e.g. [Explain reflection laws at the atomic level](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83105/) explain that if body reflects only, it cannot emit.

If tags had not made it clear, I'm looking for an explanation on quantum level.